# Issue in java hot spot when more than user request for services

Tags: java, jboss

I am working with jboss AS6 also developed some services using jbossws, when multiple user request for services , i am getting error as follows

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment
```

How to detect root and cause of this error , is that with kind of error occurred because of issue in java jvm or issue in user code or inphysical memory

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d91d7e1, pid=4164, tid=5012
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x7d7e1]
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0194d000):  VMThread [stack: 0x444d0000,0x44520000] [id=5012]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x8509bf71

Registers:
EAX=0x00000028, EBX=0x34345868, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x8509bf09
ESP=0x4451f904, EBP=0x4451f91c, ESI=0x14548278, EDI=0x145482a4
EIP=0x6d91d7e1, EFLAGS=0x00010293

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4451f904)
0x4451f904:   150410c0 000003fe 00000003 34345870
0x4451f914:   145482b0 00000003 4451f93c 6d9d8773
0x4451f924:   14548298 6db10ef0 342d7c88 022bff20
0x4451f934:   00000003 4451f948 4451f948 6d9d8b22
0x4451f944:   6db10ef0 4451f95c 6d909b14 6db1f138
0x4451f954:   6db10ef0 022bff20 4451f978 6d906019
0x4451f964:   6db10ef0 00000000 6db10ef0 6db10ef0
0x4451f974:   022bff20 4451f9b8 6d900420 00000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d91d7e1)
0x6d91d7c1:   16 8a 0d b9 5b b0 6d 84 c9 8b c8 75 08 80 e1 07
0x6d91d7d1:   80 f9 01 eb 19 83 e1 07 83 f9 05 74 24 8b 56 04
0x6d91d7e1:   8b 52 68 83 e2 07 80 fa 05 74 0c 83 f9 01 75 07
0x6d91d7f1:   a9 80 ff ff ff 74 0a 50 56 e8 31 ab 0b 00 83 c4 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000028 is an unknown value
EBX=0x34345868 is an oop
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x8509bf09 is an unknown value
ESP=0x4451f904 is an unknown value
EBP=0x4451f91c is an unknown value
ESI=0x14548278 is an oop
java.lang.String 
 - klass: 'java/lang/String'
EDI=0x145482a4 is an oop
java.util.HashMap$Entry 
 - klass: 'java/util/HashMap$Entry'


Stack: [0x444d0000,0x44520000],  sp=0x4451f904,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x7d7e1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x138773]
V  [jvm.dll+0x138b22]
V  [jvm.dll+0x69b14]
V  [jvm.dll+0x66019]
V  [jvm.dll+0x60420]
V  [jvm.dll+0x621f0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x626a0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x611ea]
V  [jvm.dll+0x685c2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5fe78]
V  [jvm.dll+0x60271]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13b1a0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11da73]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11cd4e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11d070]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11d472]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1411ac]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4d309]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x41603]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x415d6]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

VM_Operation (0x4819ec04): GenCollectForPermanentAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x46083800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x46083800 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5780, stack(0x48150000,0x481a0000)]
  0x46083000 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2604, stack(0x48100000,0x48150000)]
  0x46082c00 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1912, stack(0x480b0000,0x48100000)]
  0x46082400 JavaThread "JMX server connection timeout 84" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5748, stack(0x48060000,0x480b0000)]
  0x46082000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2480, stack(0x48010000,0x48060000)]
  0x46081800 JavaThread "JMX server connection timeout 82" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4228, stack(0x47fc0000,0x48010000)]
  0x46081000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5896, stack(0x47f70000,0x47fc0000)]
  0x46080c00 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5856, stack(0x47f20000,0x47f70000)]
  0x46080400 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5256, stack(0x44da0000,0x44df0000)]
  0x46080000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4364, stack(0x44950000,0x449a0000)]
  0x45fe8800 JavaThread "ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=956, stack(0x47ed0000,0x47f20000)]
  0x45fe8400 JavaThread "ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009-Poller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4496, stack(0x47e80000,0x47ed0000)]
  0x45fe7c00 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5064, stack(0x47e30000,0x47e80000)]
  0x45fe7800 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3024, stack(0x47de0000,0x47e30000)]
  0x45fe7000 JavaThread "http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-Poller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1844, stack(0x47d90000,0x47de0000)]
  0x45fe6c00 JavaThread "HDScanner" [_thread_blocked, id=3732, stack(0x47d40000,0x47d90000)]
  0x45fe6400 JavaThread "xnio-pool4-5" [_thread_in_native, id=1384, stack(0x47cf0000,0x47d40000)]
  0x45fe5c00 JavaThread "xnio-pool4-4" [_thread_in_native, id=2756, stack(0x47ca0000,0x47cf0000)]
  0x45fe5800 JavaThread "xnio-pool4-3" [_thread_in_native, id=1652, stack(0x47c50000,0x47ca0000)]
  0x45fe5000 JavaThread "xnio-pool4-2" [_thread_in_native, id=5308, stack(0x47c00000,0x47c50000)]
  0x46224800 JavaThread "xnio-pool4-1" [_thread_in_native, id=5572, stack(0x47bb0000,0x47c00000)]
  0x46224000 JavaThread "JCA PoolFiller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=736, stack(0x47b60000,0x47bb0000)]
  0x46223c00 JavaThread "HSQLDB Timer @8de47d" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5504, stack(0x47b10000,0x47b60000)]
  0x46223400 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=5876, stack(0x47ac0000,0x47b10000)]
  0x46223000 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=2228, stack(0x47a70000,0x47ac0000)]
  0x46222800 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=4208, stack(0x47a20000,0x47a70000)]
  0x46222400 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5468, stack(0x479d0000,0x47a20000)]
  0x46221c00 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=4632, stack(0x47980000,0x479d0000)]
  0x46221400 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=4188, stack(0x47930000,0x47980000)]
  0x46221000 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5416, stack(0x478e0000,0x47930000)]
  0x44bb8c00 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5100, stack(0x47890000,0x478e0000)]
  0x44bb8800 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4468, stack(0x47840000,0x47890000)]
  0x44bb8000 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=5620, stack(0x477f0000,0x47840000)]
  0x44bb7c00 JavaThread "JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5200, stack(0x477a0000,0x477f0000)]
  0x44bb6c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1924, stack(0x47750000,0x477a0000)]
  0x44bb7400 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2908, stack(0x47700000,0x47750000)]
  0x44bb6800 JavaThread "Transaction Reaper Worker 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4408, stack(0x476b0000,0x47700000)]
  0x44bb6000 JavaThread "Transaction Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5436, stack(0x47660000,0x476b0000)]
  0x44bb5c00 JavaThread "Listener:4713" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5008, stack(0x47610000,0x47660000)]
  0x44bb5400 JavaThread "Periodic Recovery" [_thread_blocked, id=4300, stack(0x475c0000,0x47610000)]
  0x450ea800 JavaThread "Listener:4712" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2472, stack(0x47570000,0x475c0000)]
  0x450ea000 JavaThread "Transaction Expired Entry Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5088, stack(0x47520000,0x47570000)]
  0x450e9c00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=5940, stack(0x474d0000,0x47520000)]
  0x450e9400 JavaThread "hornetq-failure-check-thread" [_thread_blocked, id=5080, stack(0x47480000,0x474d0000)]
  0x450e9000 JavaThread "Old I/O server boss (channelId: 25341025, localhost/127.0.0.1:5445)" [_thread_blocked, id=5336, stack(0x47430000,0x47480000)]
  0x450e8800 JavaThread "Thread-1 (group:HornetQ-scheduled-threads-8658191)" [_thread_blocked, id=5444, stack(0x473e0000,0x47430000)]
  0x450e8400 JavaThread "Old I/O server boss (channelId: 20598849, localhost/127.0.0.1:5455)" [_thread_blocked, id=3108, stack(0x47390000,0x473e0000)]
  0x450e7c00 JavaThread "pool-8-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4820, stack(0x47340000,0x47390000)]
  0x450e7400 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4900, stack(0x472f0000,0x47340000)]
  0x450e7000 JavaThread "Thread-0 (group:HornetQ-Asynchronous-Persistent-Writes25017556-20597295)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4840, stack(0x472a0000,0x472f0000)]
  0x462a9c00 JavaThread "Thread-0 (group:HornetQ-scheduled-threads-8658191)" [_thread_blocked, id=4940, stack(0x47140000,0x47190000)]
  0x462a9400 JavaThread "hornetq-expiry-reaper-thread" [_thread_blocked, id=5240, stack(0x470f0000,0x47140000)]
  0x462a9000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5184, stack(0x470a0000,0x470f0000)]
  0x462a8800 JavaThread "hornetq-buffer-timeout" [_thread_blocked, id=4560, stack(0x47050000,0x470a0000)]
  0x462a8400 JavaThread "AcceptorThread[ServerSocket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=0,localport=4446]]" [_thread_in_native, id=5604, stack(0x47000000,0x47050000)]
  0x462a7c00 JavaThread "ServerSocketRefresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5764, stack(0x46fb0000,0x47000000)]
  0x462a7800 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=468, stack(0x46f60000,0x46fb0000)]
  0x462a7000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1098" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5688, stack(0x46f10000,0x46f60000)]
  0x462a6800 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=5104, stack(0x46ec0000,0x46f10000)]
  0x462a6400 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1091" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4564, stack(0x46e70000,0x46ec0000)]
  0x46708c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1090" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2340, stack(0x46e20000,0x46e70000)]
  0x466ed800 JavaThread "AcceptorThread[ServerSocket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=0,localport=3873]]" [_thread_in_native, id=4716, stack(0x46dd0000,0x46e20000)]
  0x466ed000 JavaThread "ServerSocketRefresh" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5328, stack(0x45910000,0x45960000)]
  0x44ce0c00 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5532, stack(0x45960000,0x459b0000)]
  0x45288800 JavaThread "AuthenticationCacheFlushThread" [_thread_blocked, id=980, stack(0x456a0000,0x456f0000)]
  0x022b9c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=5796, stack(0x003b0000,0x00400000)]
  0x0198e000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6016, stack(0x446b0000,0x44700000)]
  0x01982800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2476, stack(0x44660000,0x446b0000)]
  0x01981800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5068, stack(0x44610000,0x44660000)]
  0x0197e400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5852, stack(0x445c0000,0x44610000)]
  0x01951c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5648, stack(0x44570000,0x445c0000)]
  0x01950800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4224, stack(0x44520000,0x44570000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x0194d000 VMThread [stack: 0x444d0000,0x44520000] [id=5012]
  0x019a9400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x44700000,0x44750000] [id=4556]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x022b7dc0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0194d000
[0x022b81d0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x46083800

Heap
 def new generation   total 78848K, used 58569K [0x042c0000, 0x09840000, 0x142c0000)
  eden space 70144K,  74% used [0x042c0000, 0x0760da08, 0x08740000)
  from space 8704K,  69% used [0x08fc0000, 0x095a4c70, 0x09840000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x08740000, 0x08740000, 0x08fc0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 77227K [0x142c0000, 0x1ed70000, 0x342c0000)
   the space 174784K,  44% used [0x142c0000, 0x18e2ad48, 0x18e2ae00, 0x1ed70000)
 compacting perm gen  total 49152K, used 49151K [0x342c0000, 0x372c0000, 0x442c0000)
   the space 49152K,  99% used [0x342c0000, 0x372bff48, 0x372c0000, 0x372c0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x022c0000, 0x02900000, 0x042c0000)
 total_blobs=3142 nmethods=2947 adapters=129 free_code_cache=27034496 largest_free_block=256

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javaw.exe
0x77b90000 - 0x77cb8000     C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
0x77810000 - 0x778ec000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x76970000 - 0x76a36000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77cd0000 - 0x77d93000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x76590000 - 0x7662d000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77b8b000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76630000 - 0x7664e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x767c0000 - 0x76888000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x7696a000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76250000 - 0x76259000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.DLL
0x763b0000 - 0x7642d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db4f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74910000 - 0x74942000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76260000 - 0x763a5000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x778f0000 - 0x7797d000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x748d0000 - 0x7490e000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x76080000 - 0x760ac000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\java.dll
0x761b0000 - 0x761b7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d609000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\management.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\net.dll
0x76440000 - 0x7646d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x76430000 - 0x76436000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x75740000 - 0x7577b000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x75950000 - 0x75955000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x75120000 - 0x7512f000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x75ab0000 - 0x75ac9000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x75a70000 - 0x75aa5000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x75cf0000 - 0x75d1c000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x760e0000 - 0x760f4000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x75a60000 - 0x75a67000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x75a30000 - 0x75a52000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x73440000 - 0x7344f000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x733c0000 - 0x733d2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x733f0000 - 0x733f8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77de9000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x75780000 - 0x75785000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73450000 - 0x73456000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x75580000 - 0x755bb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x76100000 - 0x7611e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7a6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin\rmi.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 6.0 Runtime -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\jboss-6.0.0.Final\lib\endorsed -Djava.library.path=E:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/bin/native -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: org.jboss.Main --configuration=default -b localhost -Djboss.server.base.url=file:/E:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26
PATH=native
USERNAME=rajalingam
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Vista Build 6002 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 3396264k(1439516k free), swap 10179924k(8127552k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.1-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_26-b03), built on May  4 2011 00:50:59 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Thu Apr 26 14:32:48 2012
elapsed time: 82 seconds
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: I think you would have to actually post the associated details error, or at least some information about the request or the circumstances.

Comment: @TomH i have posted my error . pls tell me how to figured it out.

Comment: can you start up jboss and then go to the process explorer and take a screen shot similar to this one - http://i.stack.imgur.com/2xYVl.png and add it to your answer.

Comment: heres another question with similar message - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767264/java-hotspot-error   which was resolved as out-of-memory error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone will come along in a minute, who has the first clue about what they are talking about, and give you a proper answer. But in the meantime you got me ;-)

There is a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/27460/24714) on gaming, where the details were given in the answer of the description of the error code `0xc0000005`, as causing invalid memory access.;

> Access violation exceptions (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION) are generated by
>   modern processors when a memory access caused by an instruction or
>   program execution does not satisfy certain conditions defined by the
>   processor architecture or memory management unit structures.

Your OS seems to be reporting about 3.2 GB of memory, but my understanding is that the 32-bit JVM is limited to about 1.5GB of Heap, so I am taking a punt that this is indicating that you have run out of memory;

```
compacting perm gen  total 49152K, used 49151K [0x342c0000, 0x372c0000, 0x442c0000)
the space 49152K,  99% used [0x342c0000, 0x372bff48, 0x372c0000, 0x372c0000)
```

---

```
jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 6.0 Runtime -Xms256m -Xmx768m 
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000  
 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 
 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\jboss-6.0.0.Final 
 \lib\endorsed -Djava.library.path=E:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/bin/native        
 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

I'm guessing that you are running out of memory, and it looks like be permGenSpace ( 99% used,  total 49152K, used 49151K) but from your options, that should grab up to 256 MB and its not entirely clear why you would get to the theoretical 32-bit max 1.5GB with the other limits applied -Xms256m -Xmx768m.